# Sum of n elements of a list with for-in loop

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to create a graph with the number of days as the x axis and the total hours as the y axis, but I don't know how to create the y axis. The code is:

```
hours_per_day = [1, 4, 3, 2, 3, 1]
days = [x for x in range(len(hours_per_day))]


def total_hours():
        y = 0
        for x in hours_per_day:
                y = x + y
        return y


plt.plot(days, total_hours, label="Total Hours")
```

And the error:

```
ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (6,) and (1,)
```

Comment: That ain't a *list*, but a `numpy.ndarray`.

Comment: You are trying to set the function itself as your y value. Check what you want your y values to be first. Your function doesn't seem like something that you would actually want either.

Comment: Do you want to plot the cumulative hours? If yes, then just do `hours_per_day = np.array([1, 4, 3, 2, 3, 1])` and then `plt.plot(days, np.cumsum(hours_per_day), label="Total Hours")` where you first `import numpy as np`

Comment: Because your `for` loop completes, with all values being thrown away, and then you return the last, _singular_ value.

Answer (score 0):

I might not grasp correctly what you're trying to achieve, but just reading the sentence "create a graph with the number of days as the x axis and the total hours as the y axis" this would simply be

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

hours_per_day = [1, 4, 3, 2, 3, 1]

plt.plot(np.cumsum(hours_per_day))

plt.show()
```

[image]